# PTIJ: Please advise me; I may be going deaf from davening!

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I think I'm getting deaf. I've heard (pun intentional) that exposure to loud noise over an extended time period causes deafness.

Well, each day - at least twice per day, I'm exposed to the loud noise caused by the *Ophanim* and the *Chayot Hakodesh*.

In the first bracha of the *Shacharit* Shema,

> והאפנים וחיות הקודש ברעש גדול...

Then, again, in ובא לציון , I get the noise from behind me:

> ואשמע אחרי קול רעש גדול

During Shabbat, I get this loud noise in the morning birkat Shema as well as in the Shacharit Kedusha

> אז בקול רעש גדול

During Mincha and Ma'ariv after Shabbat, I hear the loud noise again in ובא לציון .

I don't know how to prevent this constant exposure to the Ophanim's loud noise. I tried wearing ear plugs. But, then, I can't hear the *chazzan*'s prompt to respond ברוך כבוד ה ממקומו. So, that doesn't seem to be a good idea.

I've tried requesting the Ophanim to be quieter, but they're not cooperative.

Does anyone else have any other suggestions on what I could do to prevent such loud exposure to all that noise? Is there an audiologist that specializes in Ophanic exposure?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Less psychedelic drugs may be a good start.

Comment: @Yez I can't argue with that theory. My son is deaf, and so were my parents. Being around deaf people made me realize that they hear voices that aren't there.

Comment: @DanF Are you serious? That's cool; I never knew you had such experience.

Comment: @ezra Yes. And, I'm in the middle of writing a book about this. Problem is, I can't devote much time to it, these days.

Comment: @DanF Too much time being spent on PTIJ to write a book? :)